# Is "⤒" (UPWARDS ARROW TO BAR) (U+2912) not easily confused with "不"?

Tags: characters

WeChat official account management has this horrible looking guy for `置顶` next to the trash can:

> [image]

Steam also uses the same character for `download now`:

> [image]

> [image]

I'm pretty sure it is just this character:

## ⤒

(U+2912)

which Unicode calls:

> UPWARDS ARROW TO BAR

Is ⤒ (upwards arrow to bar) not very easily confused with `不`?

Especially in the context of WeChat's usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will never be confused, bacause 不 is not always used as a sign in public （因为“不”不太会当作一个符号来使用的）.

Answer (score 0):

No and here's why:

1. characters are seldom used as icons.
2. a single '不' as an icon doesn't seem to make any sense.
3. the trash icon beside that '⤒' indicates it also being a graphical icon.
4. characters (in most fonts) won't be that perfectly symmetrical.